Squares in $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z})^\ast$ in terms of squares in $(\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z})^\ast$
Let $p$ be an odd prime and $n$ be a positive integer. For a ring $S$, let $S^\ast$ denote the set of units in $S$. It is known that $x$ is a square in $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z})^\ast$ if and only if $x$ is a square in $(\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z})^\ast$. Can somebody help me to find a book/paper reference for this?
Thanks in advance.

You need to assume that $p$ is odd. This follows from Hensel's lemma.

Do you know about Hensel lifts?

The two square roots of $1$ form the kernel of the group homomorphism $f:x\mapsto x^2$. Therefore there are $\phi(p^n)/2$ squares in this group. A quadratic residue modulo $p^n$ is necessarily a quadratic residue modulo $p$, so the count gives the claim.

Thanks. I was looking for a book/paper reference though.

I like Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms.  More direct: https://www.google.com/books/edition/p_adic_Numbers/lu_nCAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover
